# Implicit derivative of a rational function.

Tags: derivatives

I have this equation:

$$x^2={{(x+2y)} \over {(x-2y)}}$$

I want to differentiate with respect to $x$. How do I do that without multiply the denominator by $x^2$?

I tried to apply the quotient rule, but I can't see where I made a mistake.
The answer of this derivative is:

$$y'={{(3x²-4xy-1)} \over {(2x²+2)}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead: multiply everything by $x-2y$ and rearrange to get $y$ on LHS and $f(x)$ on RHS, then take a derivative wrt $x$.

EDIT: after some algebra you get 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^3-x}{2(x^2+1)}
$$
Now apply the quotient rule

Comment: I want to know how to find the derivatives using the quotient rule. multiply by (x - 2y) will simplify and turn the equation into a polynomial.

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: if I multiply I'll have x³-2yx²=x+2y.  Solve this derivative is easy, is it possible to apply the quotient rule directly to the fraction?

Comment: Pls see the edit

Comment: Your solution is not based on implicity derivative. Could you please follow the answer of @Tim Raczkowski. Your solution is valid but I want solve using the quotient rule.

Answer (score 1):

For $x^2=(x+2y)/(x-2y)$, differentiating implicitly with respect to $x$ gives

$$\begin{align}
2x & ={(1-2y')(x+2y)-(1+2y')(x-2y)\over (x-2y)^2}\\
& = {x+2y-2xy'-4yy'-x+2y-2xy'+4yy'\over (x-2y)^2}\\
2x(x-2y)^2 & =4y-4xy'\\
y & '=-{2x(x-2y)^2+4y\over 4x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I got this. But as you can see the answer is very different from the one I get.
wy?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your work.  I suggest you go over your steps, comparing your work to mine.

Comment: I have the same result you have. But when I multiply by x² the answer is that of my question.

Comment: are the two solutions rigth?

Comment: No. Just one. See Alex's answer.

Comment: ok, but do you know where did you mistake? I did the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Deriving both members,

$$2xx'=\frac{(x'+2)(x-2y)-(x+2y)(x'-2)}{(x-2y)^2}.$$